# Comparing the structures of two graphs

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a way in TensorFlow to find out if two graphs have the same structure ?

I am designing an abstract class whose individual instances are expected to represent different architectures. I have provided an `abc.abstractmethod get()` which defines the graph. However, I also want to be able to load a pre-trained graph from disk. I want to check if the pre-trained graph has the same definition as the one mentioned in the `get()` method of a concrete class.

How may I achieve this structural comparison ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get graph definition of current graph as `str(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())` and compare for exact equality against your previous result.

Also, TensorFlow tests have more advanced function EqualGraphDef which can tell that two graphs are equal even when graph format has changed, ie, if `actual` and `expected` as GraphDef proto objects, you could do

```
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
diff = pywrap_tensorflow.EqualGraphDefWrapper(actual.SerializeToString(),
                                              expected.SerializeToString())
assert not diff
```

Comment: Does `EqualGraphDefWrapper` display ALL differences? If I print diff it appears to only show a single diff if any exist, but I am expecting more than one diff in one of my cases and I can't seem to get it to show multiple?

Comment: To clarify, I am also seeing a diff such as: ""Node named 'save/StringJoin/inputs_1' has attr 'value' with value: Tensor<type: string shape: [] values: _temp_4f6be76e8146406bb97d3171fa86af5e/part> that does not match expected: Tensor<type: string shape: [] values: _temp_ecef2ae66c5740fe94280fdaa1849660/part>" which seems just like a hashing issue and not any real difference, but I can't "move on" to see if there are any other differences..